# How to remove vertical lines representing a block in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e

```
\begin{algorithm}
\SetNoLine
\DontPrintSemicolon % Some LaTeX compilers require you to use\dontprintsemicolon instead
\KwIn{A finite set $A=\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\}$ of integers}
\KwOut{The largest element in the set}
$max \gets a_1$\;
\For{$i \gets 2$ \textbf{to} $n$} {
  \If{$a_i > max$} {
      $max \gets a_i$\;
  }
}
\Return{$max$}\;
\caption{{\sc Max} finds the maximum number}
\label{algo:max}
\end{algorithm}
```

Here \SetNoLine is not working

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Sorry.. I am new to TEX so wasn't aware of other compatibilities.
\documentclass[openright,twoside]{iitkthesis}
\usepackage[ruled,lined,boxed,algochapter,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
This is a university thesis format. Also I dont know which all this things I need to inform here

Comment: Here is template link https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/553ad96cafbf3ad60c24e2dc

Comment: As LaRiFaRi says, please create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the problem. Make a copy of your thesis and remove all you can (without changing the problem). Then edit-in that document.

Answer (score 10):

The documentation hasn't been updated (or I didn't find the information): `\SetNoLine` is deprecated, and replaced with `\SetAlgoNoLine`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

{\SetAlgoNoLine%
  \begin{algorithm}
    \DontPrintSemicolon % Some LaTeX compilers require you to use\dontprintsemicolon instead
    \KwIn{A finite set $A=\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\}$ of integers}
    \KwOut{The largest element in the set}
    $max \gets a_1$\;
    \For{$i \gets 2$ \textbf{to} $n$} {
      \If{$a_i > max$} {
        $max \gets a_i$\;
      }
    }
    \Return{$max$}\;
    \caption{{\sc Max} finds the maximum number}
    \label{algo:max}
  \end{algorithm}}%

\begin{algorithm}
  %
  \DontPrintSemicolon % Some LaTeX compilers require you to use\dontprintsemicolon instead
  \KwIn{A finite set $A=\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\}$ of integers}
  \KwOut{The largest element in the set}
  $max \gets a_1$\;
  \For{$i \gets 2$ \textbf{to} $n$} {
    \If{$a_i > max$} {
      $max \gets a_i$\;
    }
  }
  \Return{$max$}\;
  \caption{{\sc Max} finds the maximum number}
  \label{algo:max}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want no vertical lines for the whole document, you have the option `noline`:

```
\usepackage[noline]{algorithm2e}
```