# algorithm2e : 1 block without vline

Tags: vertical-alignment, algorithm2e

I'm trying do define a block without vertical line in Vline mode. For example in :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \SetKwBlock{Init}{Initialize}{}
    
    \Init{
        x $\leftarrow$ 3\;
        \eIf{a=b}{
            y $\leftarrow$ 5\;  
        }{
            y $\leftarrow$ x\;
        }
    }
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image: Wrong result]

I would like to keep the vertical line in the ifelse statement but remove it in the Initialize statement.
Is that possible ?

NB : Another way to do it may be to look for a way to indent part of the text but ii does not work in my case because indenting the text does not indent the vertical line in the ifelse statement.
Thanks in advance, I'm new to this section of StackExchange.

Comment: Possible duplicate from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250310/how-to-remove-vertical-lines-representing-a-block-in-algorithm2e?

Comment: @Sebastiano No! Please do read the question, the vertical line in the if-else-statement is supposed to stay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delay switching on the lines until after your `\Init`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ruled,noline]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \SetKwBlock{Init}{Initialize}{}
    \Init{
        x $\leftarrow$ 3\;
        \SetAlgoLined
        \eIf{a=b}{
            y $\leftarrow$ 5\;  
        }{
            y $\leftarrow$ x\;
        }
    }
  \SetAlgoNoLine
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really, nice, not documented in the package doc. And **this can be repeated several  times** in the same algo without any conflict. Thanks.

Comment: @Comevussor "not documented in the package doc" -- I think it is more a lucky coincidence that this hack works, not a feature of the package. You're welcome!